# (Android) Why i use SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage but apps dont send sms?

Tags: android, methods, smsmanager

I have use SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage but not send sms i want to method programmatically send sms Please see this code

**EDIT CODE:**

```
    public void sendEmail(View view){
            if (hasConnection() == false){
                Intent goPop = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowPopup.class);
                startActivity(goPop);
                finish();
            }
            statusOfGPS = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Set Email option
            final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto",OpsEmail, null));


            //Check Send SMS
            if (mSMSCheckbox.isChecked()){
                SMS = true;
            }else{  
                SMS = false;
            }       

            //Check GPs
            if (statusOfGPS == true){
                LocationBy = "GPS";

            }else{
                LocationBy = "INTERNET";
            }
            setUpAddress();
            //SMS true
            if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected() && SMS == true) {
                //set massage to send
                DescribeText = "This is a Emergency message \n\n PLEASE HELP ME!!! at\n\n "+
                        addressText+ "\n Location("+LocationBy+"):("+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+
                        ") \n\n Please check maps <a href='https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+","+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"&ll="+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+","+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"&z=17'>here</a>";

                //send SMS First
                String sent = "android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT";
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(sent), 0);
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(OpsPhoneNumber, null, DescribeText, pi,null);

                //send email
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Emergency Location");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(DescribeText));
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

             Log.d(TAG, "gps =" + statusOfGPS);
            }
}
```

Next line of //send SMS First

i use

> SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(OpsPhoneNumber, null,
>   DescribeText, null,null);

and in my manifest file i have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

My device to test is android 4.2.2 and 4.1.1
but apps don't send sms how to fix this?

Comment: any log? do you have the permission to do so? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS

Comment: I have a <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Answer (score 1):

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("", null, "< message body>", null, null);
```

SmsManager require, SMS_SEND permission in your android mainfest.

Comment: Yes i will try to your answer and i have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/> but sms don't send.

Comment: can you provide the logcat if possible

Comment: I'm so sorry the logcat is not show anymore for sms sending but i think there are messages too long.The normal text msg length(i.e 160 Character)i do try to use sendMultipartTextMessage[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463338/Sending-a-SMS-Message-from-an-Android-Application) Code to send a long SMS.Yeah this command it work my sms has sending but it send for one time next time this command isn't send sms.